# How to create a Custom Subject with a VF E-Mail Template?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I am trying to create the custom Subject in a `VF Email Template`, as follows

```
Subject - Case Descrition - {!Case.Description}
```

When I was using the above code while creating it

```
The HTML Email Content specified in Step 3 is not valid. Please go back 
to Step 3 and correct the following problem: Unknown property
'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.Case'
```

[image]

In the HTML Email Case why can we use Subject **Case Description - {!Case.Description}**, but not in a VF Email Template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define the subject inside a `messaging:emailTemplate` tag.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case Description - {!relatedTo.Description}"
recipientType="User" 
relatedToType="Case">
```

and put your dummy subject in that screen. Do not use the merge fields which you are currently using.